# Double Partial Derivatives of sum of variances of dependent random variables

Tags: random-variables, partial-derivative

I have the following function 
$$f(α)=Var[αX+(1−α)Y]=Var(αX)+Var[(1−α)Y]+2α(1−α)Cov(X,Y)$$

Partial derivative of this function w.r.t **α** leads us to following result 
$$f′(α)=2αVar(X)−2(1−α)Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y)(1−2α)=0$$

$$ α=\frac{Var(Y)−Cov(X,Y)} {Var(X)+Var(Y)−2Cov(X,Y} $$

This **α** is the minimum value of the function but in order to prove that it is minimum value, one has to prove that double partial derivative of the function  **f(α)** is greater than **Zero**  i.e.  **f′′(α)** > 0 . 
But upon solving for **f′′(α)** I get

$$f′′(α)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$$

How can conclude that this **f′′(α)** > 0 . Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
0\le\def\Var{\operatorname{Var}}\Var(X-Y)=\Var(X)+\Var(Y)-2\operatorname{Cov(X,Y)}\;.
$$

Indeed this is the most you can show; you cannot show $f''(\alpha)\gt0$, since for $X=Y$ $f$ is constant.

Answer (score -2):

As the [variances is always a non-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) and Var(X-Y) is always greater than zero and our equaion leads to the proof that we wanted i.e. 
$$ f′′(α) > 0$$
So it has been proved that α denotes the minimum value of the function.